# Is there a way to determine image format from a random file?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I'm using javas jai libraries and trying to figure out a way to determine correct format of a picture when a random file is given, such as image.qwe. The solution given for example here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DeterminingtheFormatofanImageinaFile.htm works well if the file is in right format, like image.jpg. But if an actual picture image.jpg is renamed to image.qwe, ImageIO.getImageReaders() returns an empty iterator.

Is this correct behaviour or should it be able to deduce that the file is actually jpg format?

Comment: Fiddled around a bit more. Renaming image.png to image.jpg and trying to guess the format works like a charm (it determines it's a PNG pic), but still looking for a possible solution if this is possible.

Comment: `ImageIO.getImageReaders(..)` *does not* determine file format based on file name ("extension"). It does so by (delegating to the various plugins, which in turn does it by) inspecting the bytes of the input. So the code you have linked above should work fine, although using `ImageIO` simply to determine image format might be a little overkill....

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use [`Files.probeContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to determine the type of the file based on its content.

This will work regardless of whether it's been renamed. As long as you're not working with such exotic types that the readers don't understand the file, it gives you an easy way to probe the file data and determine the file type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
            : originalImage.getType();
```

Here is the explanation for TYPE_INT_ARGB  :
Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components packed into integer pixels. The image has a DirectColorModel with alpha. The color data in this image is considered not to be premultiplied with alpha. When this type is used as the imageType argument to a BufferedImage constructor, the created image is consistent with images created in the JDK1.1 and earlier releases.